# How should I update a newly added column in Entity Framework Code First Migration

Tags: entity-framework

I am learning EF Code First Migrations. I have added a new column to an exiting table

```
    public partial class Test2 : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            AddColumn("dbo.Recipes", "DeafultNumberOfServes", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropColumn("dbo.Recipes", "DeafultNumberOfServes");
        }
    }
```

I want to now update the existing rows in that table and set the DeafultNumberOfServes to 4

It works in the Seed method of my Configuration class but it feels dodgy

```
        protected override void Seed(MenuPlannerDBContext context)
        {
            context.Recipes.AddOrUpdate(
              new Recipe { RecipeID = 1, Description = "Recipe 1" },
              new Recipe { RecipeID = 2, Description = "Recipe 2" },
              new Recipe { RecipeID = 3, Description = "Recipe 3" }
            );

            var result = context.Recipes.Where(x => x.DeafultNumberOfServes == 0).ToList();
            result.ForEach(x => x.DeafultNumberOfServes = 4);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

I have also tried to put it in the Migration class itself but it is as if the sql never get run and all the rows contain the default 0 in that column.

```
    public partial class Test2 : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            AddColumn("dbo.Recipes", "DeafultNumberOfServes", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
            Sql("UPDATE dbo.Recipes SET DeafultNumberOfServes = 4");
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropColumn("dbo.Recipes", "DeafultNumberOfServes");
        }
    }
```

So what would be the best way to handle adding a column and then updating all existing rows to a value?

Answer (score 0):

Reading between the lines, it looks like you want the `DeafultNumberOfServes` property to default to 4 rather than 0 if the user hasn't specified it. You can specify the database default by changing the code in the `Up` migration to this:

```
public override void Up()
{
    AddColumn("dbo.Recipes", 
              "DeafultNumberOfServes", 
              c => c.Int(nullable: false, defaultValue: 4));
}
```

This is mainly useful when you have existing data and want to add a non-nullable column without hitting an error. It doesn't mean that the value will default to 4 if the user doesn't specify it. That is because EF will send the default value for an int (i.e. zero) unless you set it in code, and that will overwrite the database value.

So you need to set the default in code. You do that by specifying it in the constructor or in a backing field (which is my preference):

```
public class Recipe
{
   private _DefaultNumberOfServes = 4;

   public int DeafultNumberOfServes
   {
      get{ return _DefaultNumberOfServes;}
      set{ _DefaultNumberOfServes = value}
   }
}
```

BTW, the reason your migration looks like it isn't working is because the migration runs  on an empty table before your seed - so there is nothing to update - the table is empty because you are using an initialiizer that is "dropping and recreating the database always". I would advise changing to a "migrate to latest version" initializer instead so that you get into the pitfalls of migrating to a database with existing data sooner rather than later.

Comment: Thanks Colin, But I do not want to set the default of the column for new rows. I want to update exiting rows to have sensible values when I add a new column. The table already existed from the first migration and contained the seed data.The seed method is probably what threw you and its is why it feels dodgy to me. As I am specifying the RecipeID when I am adding the 3 recipes, they will not get re-inserted when the second migration is run because they already exist. Then I do a blind update on any recipes with a number of serves of 0.

Comment: If I was to do a third migration, if the user set the serves to 0 the seed method would then update it back to 4. So maybe put another way I need to both seed or update exiting data only for a specific migration. Right now its working but feels wrong.  I am also using the migrate to latest version initializer.

Comment: Well, I have worked out why Sql("UPDATE dbo.Recipes SET DeafultNumberOfServes = 4"); appeared to not work. It did work, but my Seed method is doing a AddOrUpdate which then basically reverts the change because the number of serves is not specified. I assumed it only checked if the ID existed when it is actually doing an upsert.

Comment: Yes, take care with the AddOrUpdate method. http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/take-care-with-ef-4-3-addorupdate-method/